# BigQuery SLA and service credits

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Does anyone have experience measuring BigQuery's SLA and claiming service credits when it is out of SLA?

The SLA is defined by API error rate (see full details [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla)), and GCP only provide credits if the customer claims them.

Unfortunately I can't work out how to pull the API logs from the GCP console.

As far as I can tell the API logs are not provided centrally. I can log from the client using the `--apilog` flag (see [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool#debugging)), but this is not good for seeing the overall API error rate in my org across multiple clients and applications.

Does anyone know how to pull these logs? Alternatively does anyone have experience of measuring if BigQuery is within SLA and requesting credits when it is not? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you are looking for [Google Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/overview)? Search can be narrowed down by creating a query(Samples in the link provided). Also you can view error.

Another option that I see that you are looking for is in the API & Services tab in your console where you can see data about requests, latency etc etc: [image] [image]